# Custom API and Proxy in Sencha Touch 2.2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I'm using a custom proxy and API for my Sencha Touch 2.2 app.
The API is used to connect to the framework we use, which handles all data and authentication.

When I use the proxy and API without building with Sencha CMD, I don't have any problems. When I build the app with Sencha CMD, command 'sencha app build testing', the API doesn't get added correctly. It is added to the resources, but not correctly refered to from my proxy. Therefore I can't use the app, since the proxy can't load the API and gives an error.

I added the APIy to my app.json:

```
"js": [
   {
        "path": "resources/{foldername}/{APIName}.js"
   }
]
```

I think I should add it on another place as well to get it to work, but I'm not sure where. I need the API in my proxy, my proxy is in the folder 'app/{foldername}/proxy' and consists of the following elements:

```
Ext.define('{ProxyName}.proxy', {
    singleton: true,
    _api: null,
    api : function() {
        if(!this._api) {
            this._api = new {apiName}.Data;
            this._api.allowDataTransfer(true);
    }
});

Ext.define('{ProxyName}.proxy.{ProxyName}proxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Proxy',
    // implements CRUD and references to {ProxyName}.proxy.api() a few times
});
```

In app.js I set a path to my proxy in `Ext.Loader.setPath()` and added the proxy as a require.

How do I correctly add my API to my app?

Comment: I've been looking for days for a solution and couldn't find one. Now I just posted my question  here and I find a solution.

I tried to add the url to my API in the index.html just before I load the app.

Now my proxy is working correctly after building the app.

A simple solution...